# Matlab transpose of a 0x0 array

Tags: matlab, for-loop, nested, transpose

I am required to create my own array transpose routine without using transpose(x). I have to use nested for-loops to swap the columns and rows of an array. I came up with the following code however this only works for non-zero values of m and n (number of columns and rows). How can I adjust this code so that it works for n = 0 and m = 0 as well? Thanks in advance

```
clear
clc

% set dimensions
n = 2;
m = 3;

firstArray = rand(n,m);;
for ii = 1:n;
    for jj = 1:m;
       transposedArray(jj, ii) = firstArray(ii, jj); %transposing
    end
end

disp(transposedArray);
```

Comment: @m0h4mm4d: In MATLAB, this is technically allowed, so the question is not invalid in that aspect. However, I don't understand the problem in the code here, do you want to make it a function? It will work for any 2D array.

Comment: @Hoist How do you know it only works for non-zero values of `m` and `n`? Is it based on the fact that `rand(0,0)` gives error? Because that is entirely unrelated to the logic implementation, don't confuse the two.

Comment: Let me clarify further, the code that I wrote passes through the checkpoints of the system I am submitting through for m and n values that are not 0. The system then checks it for m = 0 and n = 0 (empty array) and says that my variable transposedArray is not defined. I guess just returning the empty array if it is m = 0 and n = 0 should be sufficient.

Comment: So you are not required to make a routine? Anyways, I'll post the solution below.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is check the dimensions of the array before your `for` loop, and if they are zero, return the empty matrix. **Better still, just initialize `transposedArray`**, and if any dimensions are blank the `for` loop does nothing.

```
clear
clc

% set dimensions
n = 2;
m = 3;

firstArray = rand(n,m);

transposedArray = [] % Initialize to blank

% Aside: If the arrays are large, pre-allocation can improve performance as below:
% transposedArray = zeros(size(firstArray, 2), size(firstArray, 1))

for ii = 1:n;
    for jj = 1:m;
       transposedArray(jj, ii) = firstArray(ii, jj); %transposing
    end
end

disp(transposedArray);
```

Comment: Initializing to empty makes `transposedArray` do the maximum number of allocations it can; there's never any reason not to initialize as  `transposedArray = zeros(m,n);`.

Comment: Absolutely agree.